# Game of Thrones Finale Season 7 - What decision did Jaime make?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In Season 7 finale,

> Jamie rode away from King's Landing.
>  
>  Did he disregard what the queen said and ride back to his troops to
>  continue  coordinating the army on march Northward or did he ride off
>  into exile because the queen ordered his death?

Comment: I don't hink he was really sentenced to death (see this [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/168218/why-did-the-mountain-hesitate)). Plus, he DID follow the Queen order, wich is to fight in the north. or at least it's the official order. Ordering to arrest him because he don't follow the order would mean the order was to NOT go North, and I'm not sure that he wants everybody to know that

Comment: We don't have enough information *yet* to answer this question. We will probably get an answer next year in season 8.

Comment: [Brave Ser Jaime ran away....](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l8IkbCeZ9to)

Comment: @RichS I haven't watched the episode so can't say if we can answer this or not. I trust your judgement however, so to be sure, Are we absolutely certain that we can not make an educated assessment of what happened?

Comment: @Aegon I did make an educated assessment. It is in my answer below. :-)

Comment: @RichS Yes I saw that. Close vote already retracted. are you gonna expand on it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it violates our Future Works Policy. The question can be re-opened if information is revealed in scenes that haven't been released yet.

Comment: [Why not both?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OawrlVoQqSs)

Answer (score 12):

**Jaime is leaving on his own.**

He is riding to fulfill the vow he made to Daenerys and Jon that *he* would fight the army of the dead. After seeing the dead wight, Jon Snow risking it all by telling the truth, Brienne begging him for the sake of honor, and Tyrion walking into the lion's den in last ditch effort has convince Jaime that this is the right thing to do.

Cersei even tells Jaime "No one walks away from me" and calls him a traitor right before she bluffs that Gregor will kill him. While she didn't want to kill him I don't think she wants him in command of the army any more either, especially to take it North...

This character arc even has support from the books. We see a similar situation, albeit much earlier, when Jaime is leading the Lannister army in the Riverlands. He has started to withdraw from Cersei's mental grip and has started to think about his honor as a member of the Kingsguard. The whole arc is not complete yet as the books are behind the show (obviously), but the show, even with its major deviations, still has some echos from the books.

**But don't take my word for it...**

[Take it from the official script](http://m.emmys.com/sites/default/files/collateral/118%20Game%20Of%20Thrones%20-%20The%20Dragon%20and%20the%20Wolf.pdf);

> Jaime rides north, the city behind him. He’s no longer wearing his Lannister uniform. **He’s no longer commanding an army**, or representing his house. He’s dressed so as not to stand out, in the manner of Bronn, a sellsword with no affiliations.
>
> He glances down at his golden hand, a hand that makes him famous throughout Westeros. Stopping his horse, he pulls on a black leather glove (specially designed for his golden hand). As he finishes he notices a single snowflake landing on the black leather.
>
> He looks up at the overcast sky. He glances back at the capital, and the high towers of the Red Keep. He trots forward, never looking back again, **a lone horseman heading north on the Kingsroad.**

Comment: Nikolaj says: [`I don’t believe in you anymore... I don't love you anymore.`](http://www.huffingtonpost.com.au/2017/08/28/nikolaj-coster-waldau-breaks-down-that-huge-jaime-moment-on-game-of-thrones_a_23188529/) is the reason that *he* interprets. (You're welcome to use that as a source if you'd like).

Answer (score 7):

It's obvious that Jaime is going solo to the North. **He's covering up his gold hand** to stay under the radar while traveling, while there would be no point to do so if he was leading an army. He's also wearing fairly anonymous clothes, and not the outfit of a commander.

Answer (score 1):

Jaime presumably rode north to coordinate the queen's army as it attacks the army of the dead. Those are the *official* orders. Any other orders would reveal to Jon Snow and Daenarys Targaryen that Cersei was planning to betray them all along.

It's possible that Cersei has given the army secret orders to follow should the living achieve victory over the dead. If so, Jaime may contradict those orders to prevent an alliance of the North and Daenarys Targaryen from uniting against Cersei.

We won't get an official answer until season 8 next year.

Comment: Cersei interrupts Jaime while he is just beginning to plan the route north, so it doesn't look like she wants her army to move there at all. Presumably, she tries to pull a Late Lord Frey ("Oh, I needed sooooo much time to call my banners, I am veeeeeery sorry that I couldn't make it in time. Hey, are those couple hundred men all that is left of your army?").

Comment: Actually, forget about Lord Frey, she probably rather found inspiration in her father's strategy during Robert's Rebellion.